# What does number#number#number identifies in FreeMarker log error?

Tags: freemarker

I am using [FreeMarker Java Template Engine](http://freemarker.org/) in *Liferay Portal* and I get this error:

> 19:55:00,260 ERROR [http-bio-80-exec-2][runtime:96] Template
>   processing error: "Error on line 290, column 1 in
>   **924629#924665#3296702** request['theme-display'] is undefined. It can not
>   be assigned to themeDisplay"

I want to know what this number `924629#924665#3296702` identifies or mean?

Comment: It's on the place where FreeMarker prints the template name. It's some generated template name.

Comment: Thank you @ddekany so that numbers are the id of the template?

Comment: The name of it, yes. How Liferay generates that I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
companyId#companyGroupId#templateId
```

I have found what is the meaning of those numbers. 
The first is the Company ID (`ThemeDisplay.getCompanyId()`) and the second number is the Company Group ID (`ThemeDisplay.getCompanyGroupId()`) and the last number is the ID of FreeMarker Template (Liferay templateKey)